# How should I integrate with and package this third-party library in a Win32 C++ app?

Tags: c++, windows, com, shared-libraries, kml

We have a (very large) existing codebase for a custom ActiveX control, and I'd like to integrate [`libkml`](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/) into it for the sake of interacting with KML mapping data, rather than reinventing the wheel. The problem is, I'm a relatively new Windows developer, and coming from the Linux world, I'm really not sure what the *right* way of integrating a third party library is. Thankfully, `libkml` does provide MSVCC projects for compiling it, so porting isn't a problem. I guess I have a couple choices that I can think of:

1. **Build and link the library directly**. We already have a solution with project files in it for the "main" project; I could add the `libkml` projects to that solution, but I'd rather not. It's very unlikely that the `libkml` code will change in relation to our app's code.
2. **Statically link to the `.lib` files produced by the `libkml` build**. This is unattractive, since there are six `.lib` files that come out of the `libkml` solution and it seems inelegant to manually specify them in the linker options, etc.
3. **Package the code as-is in a DLL**. Maybe with COM? It seems like if I did this without any translation, I'd end up with a lot of overhead, and since I'm fairly unfamiliar with COM, I don't know how much work would be involved in exposing all the functionality I'd like to use via COM. The library is fairly big, has a lot of classes it uses, and if I had to manually write code to expose it all, I'd be hesitant to go this route.
4. **Write wrapper code to to abstract the functionality I need, package that in a COM DLL, and interact with that**. This *seems* sensible, I suppose, but it's difficult to determine how much abstraction I need since I haven't written the code that would use `libkml` yet.

Let me reiterate: I haven't yet written the code that will interact with `libkml` yet, so this is mostly experimental. Options 1 and 2 are also complicated by the fact that `libkml` relies additionally on three more external libraries that are also in `.lib` files (that I had to recompile anyways to get the code generation flags to line up). The goal obviously is to get the code to work, but maintainability and source tree organization are also goals, so I'm leaning towards options 3 and 4, but I don't know the best way to approach those on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing six file names, or using the declarative style with #pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib") is small potatoes compared to the work you'll have to do to turn this into a DLL or COM server.

The distribution is heavily biased towards using this as a static link library.  There are only spotty declarations available to turn this into a DLL with __declspec(dllexport).  They exist only in the 3rd party dependencies.  All using different #defines of course, you'll by typing a bunch of names in the preprocessor definitions for the projects.

Furthermore, you'll have a hard time actually getting this DLL loaded at runtime since you are using it in a COM server.  The search path for DLLs will be the client app's when COM creates your control instance, not likely to be anywhere near close to the place you deployed the DLL.

Making it a COM server is a *lot* of work, you'll have to write all the interface glue yourself.  Again, nothing already in the source code that helps with this at all.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I'll go the statically linked route, then. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can also wrap all the functionality you need in a non-COM-dll. Visual studio supports creating a static wrapper library which, when linked, will make your program use the dll. This way you only have one dependency to specify instead of six.

Other than that, what is wrong with specifying six dependencies. I would assume that there is a good reason that these are six separate libraries instead of one, so it is prudent to specify exactly which parts you actually use.

Comment: Well, right now, I actually have all the libraries specified as dependencies (which is nine total: the six `libkml` libraries plus `zlib`, `uriparser`, and `expat`), but if I compile code that actually links to any of that, the whole thing silently breaks. It also seems hairy from a maintainability standpoint, I suppose.

Comment: @Wyatt: I know the problem. We use wrapper-dlls like I describe in my answer for that.

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation for doing so? I tried to create a "wrapper" project with the six individual projects as dependencies and output specified as a .DLL, but nothing actually ever seems to get built, and it seemed to get to the manifest generation phase and complain about the .DLL not existing.

Comment: @Wyatt: We do it like you describe in your 4th idea. We write actual wrapper code that exposes the functionality we need. Documentation is provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx).

Comment: If things "silently break" doesn't that imply some type of bug or other potential problem.  How does wrapping this in a DLL help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I really don't see what is wrong with (1).  I think that even if you had multiple projects that were using libkml, just insert the project file for libkml into your solution file, specify the dependencies, and you should be done.  It's dead simple.  Even solution (2) is dead simple.  If the libraries ever change, you rebuild - you're going to need to do that anyway.

I'm failing to see how (3) or (4) are necessary or even desired.  To me, it sounds like a lot of work for goals (source tree organization and maintainability) that I'm not even sure that those options really meet.  In fact, you said yourself that "It's very unlikely that the libkml code will change in relation to our app's code."

What I've found over the years is to just keep things simple.  If rebuilding KML is potentially time consuming, grab the libs and just statically link to the libraries.  Yes, there are other dependencies, but you'll set this up once and be done, hopefully never to worry about it again.  Otherwise, stick it in the project and move on.  I think that it's worthwhile to ask whether spending a lot of time on this issue is worth the trouble.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was going to say; keep things simple.  Options 3 and 4 are overkill; I would slightly prefer option 2 as it is simply a one-time setup cost whereas option 1 has to compile the project for each build (not a big deal with today's hardware, but it's one less moving part).